# What is the equivalent of Python list, set, and map comprehensions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

In Python, there are list comprehensions and similar constructs for maps and sets.  In Kotlin there is nothing at all in any of the documentation with a similar name.

What are the equivalents of these comprehensions? For example, those found in [Python 3 Patterns, Recipes and Idioms](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html).  Which includes comprehensions for:

- list
- set
- dictionary

***Note:*** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Kotlin topics are present in SO.*

Comment: Questions of the form "how what is the equivalent of language X feature in language Y" does not need to have any language X tags associated with it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Taking examples from [Python 3 Patterns, Recipes and Idioms](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) we can convert each one to Kotlin using a simple pattern.  The Python version of a list comprehension has 3 parts:

1. output expression
2. input list/sequence and variable
3. optional predicate

These directly correlate to Kotlin functional extensions to collection classes.  The input sequence, followed by the optional predicate in a `filter` lambda, followed by the output expression in a `map` lambda.  So for this Python example:

```py
# === PYTHON

a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

#                    output | var | input   | filter/predicate 
even_ints_squared = [ e*e  for e in a_list  if e % 2 == 0 ]

print(even_ints_squared)
# output: [ 4, 16, 36 ]
```

Becomes

```
// === KOTLIN

var aList = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

//                    input      |   filter      |       output              
val evenIntsSquared = aList.filter { it % 2 == 0 }.map { it * it }

println(evenIntsSquared)
// output: [ 4, 16, 36 ]
```

Notice that the variable is not needed in the Kotlin version since the implied `it` variable is used within each lambda.  In Python you can turn these into a lazy generator by using the `()` instead of square brackets:

```py
# === PYTHON

even_ints_squared = ( e**2 for e in a_list if e % 2 == 0 )
```

And in Kotlin it is more obviously converted to a lazy sequence by changing the input via a function call `asSequence()`:

```
// === KOTLIN

val evenIntsSquared = aList.asSequence().filter { it % 2 == 0 }.map { it * it }
```

---

Nested comprehensions in Kotlin are created by just nesting one within the other's `map` lambda.  For example, take this sample from [PythonCourse.eu](https://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) in Python changed slightly to use both a set and a list comprehension:

```py
# === PYTHON

noprimes = {j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 100, i)}
primes = [x for x in range(2, 100) if x not in noprimes]
print(primes)
# output: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Becomes:

```
// === KOTLIN

val nonprimes = (2..7).flatMap { (it*2..99).step(it).toList() }.toSet()
val primes = (2..99).filterNot { it in nonprimes }
print(primes)    
// output: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Notice that the nested comprehension produces a list of lists which is converted to a flat list using `flatMap()` and then converted to a set using `toSet()`.  Also, Kotlin ranges are inclusive, whereas a Python range is exclusive so you will see the numbers are slightly different in the ranges.

You can also use a `sequence` generator with co-routines in Kotlin to yield the values without needing the call to `flatMap()` or `flatten()`:

```
// === KOTLIN

val nonprimes = sequence {
    (2..7).forEach { (it*2..99).step(it).forEach { value -> yield(value) } }
}.toSet()
val primes = (2..99).filterNot { it in nonprimes }
```

---

Another example from the referenced Python page is generating a matrix:

```py
# === PYTHON

matrix = [ [ 1 if item_idx == row_idx else 0 for item_idx in range(0, 3) ] for row_idx in range(0, 3) ]
print(matrix)
# [[1, 0, 0], 
#  [0, 1, 0], 
#  [0, 0, 1]]
```

And in Kotlin:

```
// === KOTLIN

val matrix = (0..2).map { row -> (0..2).map { col -> if (col == row) 1 else 0 }}
println(matrix)
// [[1, 0, 0], 
//  [0, 1, 0], 
//  [0, 0, 1]]
```

Or in Kotlin instead of lists, you could also generate arrays:

```
// === KOTLIN

val matrix2 = Array(3) { row -> 
                          IntArray(3) { col -> if (col == row) 1 else 0 } 
                       }
```

---

Another of the examples for set comprehensions is to generate a unique set of properly cased names:

```py
# === PYTHON

names = [ 'Bob', 'JOHN', 'alice', 'bob', 'ALICE', 'J', 'Bob' ]

fixedNames = { name[0].upper() + name[1:].lower() for name in names if len(name) > 1 }

print(fixedNames)
# output: {'Bob', 'Alice', 'John'}
```

Is translated to Kotlin:

```
// === KOTLIN

val names = listOf( "Bob", "JOHN", "alice", "bob", "ALICE", "J", "Bob" )

val fixedNames = names.filter { it.length > 1 }
       .map { it.take(1).toUpperCase() + it.drop(1).toLowerCase() }
       .toSet()

println(fixedNames)
// output: [Bob, John, Alice]
```

---

And the example for map comprehension is a bit odd, but can also be implemented in Kotlin.  The original:

```py
# === PYTHON

mcase = {'a':10, 'b': 34, 'A': 7, 'Z':3}

mcase_frequency = { k.lower() : mcase.get(k.lower(), 0) + mcase.get(k.upper(), 0) for k in mcase.keys() }

print(mcase_frequency)
# output: {'a': 17, 'z': 3, 'b': 34}
```

And the converted, which is written to be a bit more "wordy" here to make it clearer what is happening:

```
// === KOTLIN

val mcase = mapOf("a" to 10, "b" to 34, "A" to 7, "Z" to 3)

val mcaseFrequency = mcase.map { (key, _) ->
    val newKey = key.toLowerCase()
    val newValue = mcase.getOrDefault(key.toLowerCase(), 0) +
                   mcase.getOrDefault(key.toUpperCase(), 0)
    newKey to newValue
}.toMap()

print(mcaseFrequency)
// output: {a=17, b=34, z=3}
```

---

Further reading:

- Kotlin adds more power than list/set/map comprehensions because of its extensive functional transforms that you can make to these collection types.  See [What Java 8 Stream.collect equivalents are available in the standard Kotlin library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr)
   for more examples.
- See [Get Factors of Numbers in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50318157/3679676)
   which shows another example of a Python comprehension versus Kotlin.
- See [Kotlin Extensions Functions for Collections](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html) in the API reference guide.

Comment: Very nice answer, @Jayson! A small question: you use `.map { it }` in a couple of place - can it be omitted?

Comment: @Tom That is converting the range iteration into a list of the items in the range. I think at the time I was trying to keep it lazy coming out of an iterator but `map` converts to a list anyways, so I am editing the above examples to have `toList()`

Comment: I made other slight cleanups to be a touch more modern.

Answer (score 1):

Just for exercise the closest to python will be:

```
infix fun <I, O> ((I) -> O).`in`(range: Iterable<I>): List<O> = range.map(this).toList()
infix fun <I> Iterable<I>.`if`(cond: (I) -> Boolean): List<I> = this.filter(cond)

fun main() {
    { it: Int -> it + 1 } `in` 1..2 `if` {it > 0}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Map comprehension**

```
import kotlin.math.sqrt

val numbers = "1,2,3,4".split(",")

val roots = numbers.associate { n -> n.toInt() to sqrt(n.toFloat()) }

println(roots)  // prints {1=1.0, 2=1.4142135, 3=1.7320508, 4=2.0}
```

If keys are untransformed elements of source list, even simpler:

```
val roots = numbers.associateWith { n -> sqrt(n.toFloat()) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val newls = (1..100).filter({it % 7 == 0})
```

in Kotlin is equivalent to the following Python code

```
newls = [i for i in 0..100 if i % 7 ==0]
```